# How to tell spark where a file should be split to inputs?

Tags: apache-spark

I am looking for something equivalent to hadoop's `InputFormat`. But I do not have a `.java` class from Hadoop. My question is how is this done in spark, without using Hadoop's way of identifying inputs.
Sorry if this is a dumb question but I am extremly new to Hadoop/Spark.
Thanks

Comment: For reading files Spark depends on Hadoop input formats.

Comment: So, writing a custom InputFormat is a neccessary step? If so, then thanks, at least now I know how to continue. Any ~babysteps~ documentation where I can learn more?

Comment: I believe any Hadoop guide will do just fine.

Comment: You can also use dataFrame to read diffrent -2 format  ,ex  :                                       val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)                             sqlContext.read.

Answer (score 0):

I am taking a presumption that in case of MR `InputFormat` data will be small as it is mostly used to define coherent data groups (to be processed in single map or MR). So it is unlikely that file which is defining coherent group in too big to fit in memory. So it is possible to read the data from `InputFormat` and cache it in memory in case of Spark. Later you can read the content of this file, create an iterator (which will identify the data part say Hive partition) and then generating dynamic path for data part using this iterator.